# Saving a Word document as PDF, but with Bookmarks?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, bookmarks, pdf-reader

In PDF's you can have a headings/bookmarks side panel that lets you jump to different chapters or sections (of course, not all PDF's, just those where these have been added).

In Word, I can "Save a Copy" as PDF, and I find the rendering to be really good/accurate. However, I would like to also create headings Bookmarks into the Word document that are saved into the PDF. I have tried creating Word Bookmarks, and this doesn't work, i.e., when I save to PDF, the bookmarks are not there (the "Show Bookmarks" option in PDF readers is greyed out, so they are not there).

How can I create Bookmarks in MS Word that will give me chapter/heading/section bookmarks in PDF when I save to a PDF?

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like this :

- In Word, click the **File** tab and click **Save As**
- Select "*.pdf" from the **Save as type** drop-down list
  (and possibly set also the folder and file-name)
- Click **Options** and set "Create bookmarks using: Headings"
- Click Save.

Note : This option is only available for `.docx` documents.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I've spent some time looking for this Option for PDF's and just can't see it. On Office 365, there is a "More options..." under the save options and I've hunted around in there and do not see "Create bookmarks using: Headings" do you have some screenshots for this please?

Comment: Image added and also a note about `.docx`.

Comment: This option is not available for Word on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Word 2016, I don't get the Options menu when using the Save As method. To create the PDF with heading etc available you need to :

Go to **File** > **Export** > **Create PDF/XPS**

Click on **Options...**

You'll now see the **Include non-printing information** section which includes the option to **Create bookmarks using:** and you can select either **Headings** or **Word bookmarks**

[image: File > Export menu]

[image: Options menu]

Answer (score 0):

Video instruction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10f5YDNtsQs

Text instruction:

1. Go to "File" > "Save As" > "Browse"
2. In the new window, open the dropdown menu at the bottom and select "PDF"
3. A new "Options" button appears, click on it and check the box for "Create bookmarks using" together with the option "Headings"